# Google Places API OVER_QUERY_LIMIT

Tags: google-places-api

I'm working on a script which sends a few hundreds of API calls to Google Places API using the [nearbySearch]. After a few requests, I quickly get an `OVER_QUOTA_LIMIT` error.

In Google Cloud Console, I can see the requests made in the last days or hours but:

1. I'm a far cry from the 6 000 requests/minutes limit
2. I don't see any `Quota Exceed Error` in the graph

(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests)

[image: Requests per minute and quotas]

[image: REquests per day/hour]

If I scroll down a bit, I can see that there's apparently a "Premium Plan", but no request have been made up to now.

[image: Premium Plan Requests and quotas]

Now I can see that [the Premium Plan is not available anymore for sign up or new customers.](https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/faq#premium_def).
So I guess it's just a graph to support people who have previously signed for this plan but that it is not relevant in my case.

My payment settings have been set up correctly so I don't understand what's happening here.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Probably need to contact your google rep...

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/usage-and-billing#other-usage-limits

Comment: I think I make far less than 100 places call per sec but it's a useful info.